# Migrate delta lake from Azure to GCP

Tags: azure, databricks, delta-lake

we are looking to migrate our delta lake from Azure to GCP.
So far we are thinking about moving delta files from one ADLS bucket to GCS bucket. We believe there might be more to that.
We are looking for a methodology, best practices and hints on to do that migrationo. Can anybody help on that please.

Comment: Haven't come across any best practices, but copying the files including the delta log and then re-creating the table does work. Do take care that if you have n partitions in ADLS and you copy over folders of only x partitions, then all the n partitions do show up with some partitions being empty. Also do take care about the non-delta table types and how they work o re-creation. Used to have some issues, but its been a long time now and things should basically work out...

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check [sources and sinks of the Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/sources-and-sinks). One of the sources - is an `Azure Blob Storage, including Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2` - I don't know if that can help in your case. And some [documentation about access configuration](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/source-microsoft-azure).

All other details - depends on you case, and it is very difficult to provide a general answer.